# Pass the type of a generic method in a variable

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core

I have several class `ClassA`,`ClassB`.

I would like to pass the type to a generic function, something like:

```
var myTypeToPass=new ClassA();   

using(var context=_contextFactory.CreateDbContext())
{
    var test = context.Set<Here is myTypeToPass>();
}
```

Is it possible?

The idea is to keep the same code for the same tests, but with different entities.

Comment: Well yes. What have you tried?

Comment: `myTypeToPass` is an instance, not a type. Are you trying to call `contest.Set<ClassA>()`?

Comment: Yes I try to pass ClassA or ClassB  to Set<>

Comment: @Manta why? This smells like yet another attempt at creating a "generic repository" when DbSet is already that, and DbContext is the multi-entity Unit-of-Work. For tests, you can create a generic method and use `Set<T>()`. You still have to configure the entity though

Comment: I have one test class by controller. If I want to reuse the code in all controllers I don't want to hard code the entity type and I can't use dbcontext.MyEntity or dbcontext.set<MyEntity>. That's why the idea would to use a variable during instantiation for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok finally, I did it:

```
public class MyClassTests
{
    private readonly Entity _entity = new Entity();


    private DbSet<T> GetDbSet<T>(DbContext context, T entityOfDbSet) where T : class
    {
        return context.Set<T>();
    }

    public async Task Post_EntityName_ReturnsSameEntity()
    {
        using (var context = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext())
        {
             var dbSet = GetDbSet(context, _entity );              
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly did you do? You can replace that line with just `var dbSet = context.Set<Entity>();` and you get the same result.

Answer (score 6):

```
void DoSomething<T>()
{
  using var ctx = CtxFactory.Create();
  var test = ctx.Set<T>();
}
```

And then you can use it like so

```
DoSomething<ClassA>();
```

If you already have an instance of a certain type and need to do something with it, you can still do it:

```
void DoSomething<T>( T myArg )
{
    ...
    var test = ctx.Set<T>();
}
```

And usage

```
var instance = new ClassA();
DoSomething(instance);
```

Note how the type argument will be inferred here.